# How can I link my app to a Facebook id different from the id in the Facebook app?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I use the Facebook SDK to connect my app with the user's Facebook account.  By default, the Facebook SDK automatically uses the current logged in account from the Facebook App.

I want to allow users to login with a different account.

Is this possible?  If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the SwitchUserSample in the Facebook SDK for iOS for an example of how to do this.  If you do this, you should have some UI in your application that provides users the ability to choose between logging in via the facebook application or logging in as a different user.